# How to access JSON data via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to access jsongrid value in radio button (gender field) without applying html.I tried simple javascript function which is working fine in UI but the value coming through html input but I want value come from jsongrid.Plz help me out..

this is JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j.ajax({
        url:"UserGender",
        type: "GET",
        data: datasourses,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data){
            $.each(data, function(i, selectedItem) {
                alert("paramValue: " + selectedItem.paramValue + ", paramCode: " +    
                data.selectedItem.paramCode);
            });
        }       
    });
</script>
```

This is html

```
<input type="radio" name="Female" >
<input type="radio" name="Male" >
```

Json code

```
{
    "jsonWrapperforGrid": {
        "page": "1",
        "total": "2",
        "rows": [
            {
                "tenantId": 0,
                "paramType": "UserGender",
                "paramCode": "F",
                "langCode": "en",
                "paramValue": "Female"
            },
            {
                "tenantId": 0,
                "paramType": "UserGender",
                "paramCode": "M",
                "langCode": "en",
                "paramValue": "Male",
                "paramBlob": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please could you tell exactly what `each()` should print? what's the expected output?

Comment: `data` will be an object only containing one property, `jsonWrapperforGrid`. If you want to access the array in `rows`, it would be `data.jsonWrapperforGrid.rows`. This is JavaScript 101, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $.each(data.jsonWrapperforGrid.rows, function() {
    alert("paramValue: " + this.paramValue + ", paramCode: " +    this.paramCode);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.I want to access my json data in html table without using the value attribute inside input tag but I am unable to get the data in UI ...I want the javascript to solve this problem..

Comment: i honestly can't tell what you are trying to ask. You may want to clean up your question, grammatically.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar  Just check th e json code in that , " param value & param code"  I can access these value by html which i have mentioned . but i want to access with help of javascript. in short i want javascript code to access json. hope u get it ......